# Can't find jemalloc while building MariaDB on Raspbian Wheezy

Tags: cmake, raspberry-pi, mariadb, raspbian

I have installed the list of Required tools shown on the [Build Environment Setup for Linux](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/Build_Environment_Setup_for_Linux/), including JEMALLOC, on my Raspberry Pi which has Raspbian Wheezy installed, fully updated, and setup for development. I have successfully built some of the listed tools (Bison, CMake 3.7.2). I have gcc and g++ (Raspbian 4.8.2-21rpi3rpi1) 4.8.2.

When I attempt to build mariadb 10.1.22 (master branch from the github repository) using `cmake . -DBUILD_CONFIG=mysql_release` I get an error:

```
CMake Error at cmake/jemalloc.cmake:38 (MESSAGE):
  jemalloc is not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:343 (CHECK_JEMALLOC)
```

After building JEMALLOC, I installed it into `/usr/local` using `sudo make install`. I have export `JEMALLOC_PATH=/usr/local` in my `.bashrc`.

I don't understand why CHECK_JEMALLOC is failing to find the correct files. A list of the file locations is:

```
/usr/local/bin/jemalloc.sh
/usr/local/bin/jemalloc-config
/usr/local/include/jemalloc
/usr/local/include/jemalloc/jemalloc.h
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/jemalloc.pc
/usr/local/lib/libjemalloc.so
/usr/local/lib/libjemalloc_pic.a
/usr/local/lib/libjemalloc.so.2
/usr/local/lib/libjemalloc.a
/usr/local/share/doc/jemalloc
/usr/local/share/doc/jemalloc/jemalloc.html
/usr/local/share/man/man3/jemalloc.3
```

I can attach a link to the CMake configure log, error log, and terminal output if needed.

**UPDATE**
I tried using just `cmake .` and the configuration part worked, but the make failed with the following error:

```
/home/user/Downloads/mariadb/server/storage/mroonga/vendor/groonga/lib/expr.c:6816:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘GRN_PTR_POP’
   GRN_PTR_POP(&keywords, keyword);
   ^
cc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs> for instructions.
storage/mroonga/vendor/groonga/lib/CMakeFiles/libgroonga.dir/build.make:257: recipe for target 'storage/mroonga/vendor/groonga/lib/CMakeFiles/libgroonga.dir/expr.c.o' failed
make[2]: *** [storage/mroonga/vendor/groonga/lib/CMakeFiles/libgroonga.dir/expr.c.o] Error 4
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/user/Downloads/mariadb/server'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4420: recipe for target 'storage/mroonga/vendor/groonga/lib/CMakeFiles/libgroonga.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [storage/mroonga/vendor/groonga/lib/CMakeFiles/libgroonga.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/Downloads/mariadb/server'
Makefile:152: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: you do not need -DBUILD_CONFIG=mysql_release. it will work without.

Comment: @VladislavVaintroub: Thanks, *yes**, it did complete the configuration, and now I'm compiling (2% atm).  My primary concern though is to maintain the 'drop-in' compatibility with mySQL (hence the use of the option).  Have you tried the resulting binary in a LAMP arrangement on the _Pi_? (I'm planning to use Apache).

Comment: Never tried the Pi.  -DBUILD_CONFIG=mysql_release is how MariaDB is doing release builds (debian,rpm packages, tar,gz),it does not affect the drop-in-ness. You don't have to have all of those the options.jemalloc for example is just there for the TokuDB storage engine, and it is  known to be hard to compile most of the times (you can avoid this engine with -DTOKUDB_OK=0). If you really want to know what mysql_release does, look at cmake/build_configurations/mysql_release.cmake - it does some compile flags fixes, external libraries config, also embedded library is built. Nothing much otherwise.

Comment: The build failed during the make with the error: _cc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)_.  It asks to submit an error report, but I'm not sure who to report the error to; MariaDB or GNU CC, and I've never submitted such a report.  I am trying to make after using `cmake . -DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS='-ljemalloc'  -DWITH_SAFEMALLOC=OFF` which I saw someone use, and if that fails, I'll try your suggestions next.

Comment: If compiler throws an internal compiler error, it is compiler problem. MariaDB cannot help here.

Comment: Yes.  I've followed it up and hopefully something will come out of it.  I'll comeback when needed.